# PHP - Retrieve existing stripe customer and their cards?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm successfully able to create a new customer in Stripe via my PHP backend. That being said, when my user wants to view their existing cards, the PHP below just creates another new user and ephemeral key. If I already have a customer ID, how can I change my below code to make it so that if I'm providing the customer ID, existing cards are returned? Help is greatly appreciated!

```
if (!isset($_POST['api_version']))
{
 header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
}

//USER DETAILS

$email = $_POST['email'];


$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  'email' => $email, 
));


try {

    $key = \Stripe\EphemeralKey::create(
      ["customer" => $customer->id],
      ["stripe_version" => $_POST['api_version']]
    );


    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    exit(json_encode($key));
} catch (Exception $e) {
     header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error'); 
}
```

Comment: Have you checked [the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/retrieve?lang=php)?

Comment: @PatrickQ Many times, lol. I'm definitely lost. The Stripe iOS SDK tutorial appears to create a new customer every time the handlePaymentMethods button is tapped. I'm just unsure about how to code my php file so that this doesnt happen :/ Pardon my newb-ness.

Comment: A new customer is being created because you are calling `Customer::create()`.  If you don't want to create a new customer, don't call the function that creates a new customer.  I linked right to the spot that shows what function to use.  Show an attempt to use that function, and if you are still stuck, update your question with additional details.

Comment: Yes, but I need to call Customer::create() the FIRST time only - I'm asking how I can write some kind of statement that says if customer_id exists, don't execute create method lol :/ (PHP is not my forte) @PatrickQ

Comment: This is just a [copy and paste](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/standard) of the docs. You haven't tried anything nor mentioned you're trying to link to iOS. [Example](https://github.com/stripe/example-ios-backend/blob/master/web.rb) of what you want is here, just rewrite it in PHP!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to store the customer id you get back from stripe the first time you create a customer and then you can retrieve the user with:

```
\Stripe\Customer::retrieve($customer_id);
```

Something like this:

```
$customer_id = $_POST['customer_id']; //get this id from somewhere a database table, post parameter, etc.

// if the customer id doesn't exist create the customer
if ($customer_id !== null) {
    // create the customer as you are now

} else {
    $cards = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($customer_id)->sources->all()
    // return the cards
}
```

Comment: I know this, but how can I stop a new customer from being created if customer_id exists in my php code?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the general idea. You'll need to make sure you are storing the customer id somewhere and passing it into the request.

Comment: This is super helpful - will give it a try! That said, if I don't post anything to $customer_id, my PHP file breaks? Even with the if null statement?